# How to save Env variable persistently

Tags: bash, go, environment-variables

When the service starts, a session key is generated and I try to put it in an environment variable to use in the future (also when restarting the service).

I used *os.Setenv()* for this, but after restarting, the environment variable is empty.

```js
sessionKey := os.Getenv(_sessionKey)
if sessionKey == "" {
  sessionKey = string(securecookie.GenerateRandomKey(32))
  os.Setenv(_sessionKey, sessionKey)
}
sessionsStore := sessions.NewCookieStore([]byte(sessionKey))
```

Is there another way to use environment variables for this purpose, or it's better to save it to a file?

Comment: Environment variables only exist in the context of a process (and its sub-processes, if any). When the process terminates its environment variables go away.

Comment: you need to save it somewhere else and provide it to your app as env variable on startup.

Comment: Note that environment vars are not a persistent data store. As others have already commented, env vars are private to each process and only exist as long as the process runs. When a program is run its parent process gives it either a copy of its env vars (this is the usual case) or a set of custom env vars. When you call os.SetEnv() it only affects the running process and any program it runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used 'viper' lib to save env variables to the file:

```
func Getenv(key string) string {
    viper.SetConfigType("env")
    viper.SetConfigFile(".env")

    err := viper.ReadInConfig()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error while reading config file %s", err)
    }

    value, ok := viper.Get(key).(string)
    if !ok {
        return ""
    }

    return value
}

func Setenv(key string, value string) {
    viper.SetConfigType("env")
    viper.SetConfigFile(".env")

    err := viper.ReadInConfig()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error while reading config file %s", err)
    }

    viper.Set(key, value)

    err = viper.WriteConfig()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error while writing config file %s", err)
    }
}
```